# App rejected due to 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

This is what Apple have written back:

> Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase
>
> Your app or metadata includes an account registration feature, which
>   is considered an access to external mechanisms for purchases or
>   subscriptions to be used in the app. Specifically, your app
>   description contains a link to your website where users can register.

This is what they said to resolve the issue:

> To resolve this issue, please remove the account registration feature
>   and any other fully qualified links to your site that could indirectly
>   provide access to these mechanisms, such as links to web pages for
>   support, FAQs, product or program details, etc.

The app I'm developing is a B2B app where in a company can buy a subscription via the website and register its employees as users. What Apple is saying is that this is considered an external mechanism and that you should only use in-app purchases. The thing is that even if in-app purchase is implemented, because it is a B2B app and not a B2C, not every user has to buy a subscription, only a company has to buy one. It would help knowing if someone has gone through similar issues and what it took to resolve them.

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because not only is it not a question, but it's also discussing something that's the purview of Apple support, not a topic that can be answered within the confines of the [help].

Comment: My app was rejected for the same reason. I implemented other payment options only after seeing other similar apps using it. It is weird that Apple lets other similar app to have all sort of payment options and not our app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You will need to go in the resolution centre and explain them in detail your issue. My previous company used to have a B2B app with a company based subscription outside the AppStore. To pass Apple verifications, we had to discuss that with them in details and highlight the fact your app is a B2B one.

Here is an interesting post:
https://www.designernews.co/stories/9695-how-do-apps-like-lyft-uber-airbnb-skirt-apples-30-cut-on-each-transaction

Comment: can we use webview for that purpose? any idea

Answer (score 7):

RomOne's answer helped us getting our app approved into the appstore. In our case the appeal board concluded with:

*App Store Review Guideline 3.1.1, while the app is free to download, users have to make payment for ****** service. Apps that operate across multiple platforms may allow users to access content, subscriptions, or features they have acquired elsewhere, provided those items are also available as in-app purchases within the app.*

After explaining to B2B usage of the app, where companies need to have a subscription and not the employees/users of the app, and stating that this in-app purchase feature would never be used by these users, we finally got our app back in the appstore.

Comment: Thanks Gert, we're in the same situation so it's good to know that there's an approach to take

Comment:   This is great, thank you. I had to explain the B2B nature of my app and also, as @dsplatanov suggested below, quoted my app as being conformant to guideline 3.1.3(f). I explained to Apple Review in a concise 12-line paragraph the workflows users must go through so that they could see there was no purchase needed on the part of regular users. Purchases are only for admins/owners who created businesses on my platform via the web app.

Answer (score 3):

In your communication with Apple you can point to the following clauses of the App Store Review Guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), if applicable (it was applicable in my case):

> 3.1.3 Other Purchase Methods: The following apps may use purchase methods other than in-app purchase. Apps in this section cannot,
> within the app, encourage users to use a purchasing method other than
> in-app purchase. Developers can send communications outside of the app
> to their user base about purchasing methods other than in-app
> purchase.
>
> 3.1.3(c) Enterprise Services: If your app is only sold directly by you to organizations or groups for their employees or students (for
> example professional databases and classroom management tools), you
> may allow enterprise users to access previously-purchased content or
> subscriptions. Consumer, single user, or family sales must use in-app
> purchase.
>
> 3.1.3(f) Free Stand-alone Apps: Free apps acting as a stand-alone companion to a paid web based tool (eg. VOIP, Cloud Storage, Email
> Services, Web Hosting) do not need to use in-app purchase, provided
> there is no purchasing inside the app, or calls to action for purchase
> outside of the app.