# Expo RN Apple review in-app purchase issue

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, expo

On the apple review I got this response:

`Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase`

`We noticed that your app includes or accesses paid digital content, services, or functionality by means other than in-app purchase, which is not appropriate for the App Store. Specifically:`

`- The subscriptions can be purchased in the app using payment mechanisms other than in-app purchase.`

I am using `Stripe` and I am not sure what they want from me to do?

Here is my page:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [App rejected due to 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49891833/app-rejected-due-to-3-1-1-business-payments-in-app-purchase)

Comment: I am not sure tbh they are not speaking about Stripe... but is a similar situation.
I am trying to understand do I need to set something in Stripe or I can't use Stripe for a subscriptions...

Comment: You can't use stripe for subscriptions. You must use in app purchase

Comment: Refer to https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, that is it. Thank you.